# how to apply macroin sas?

Tags: if-statement, sas, macros, keyword

Submit the program shown below into the Editor window and examine the result.

```
    %macro id(num);

    proc print data=maps.algeria label noobs;

    var x y ;

    where id=&num;

    title "Projected Longitude and Latitudes for Id &num";

    run;

    %mend id;

    %id(2)
```

Modify the macro so it submits the PROC PRINT step only if the NUM parameter values between 1 and 9. If out of range the macro should write following message to the SAS log :

Id Number not found. And supplied value was: x

The value of x is the NUM parameter value.

· Resubmit the macro and call with valid and invalid parameter values and examine the results.

i have tried this

```
%macro ides(num);
%let id=%num;


%if  &num le 9 %then %do;

proc print data=maps.algeria label noobs;

var x y ;

where id=&num;

title "Projected Longitude and Latitudes for Id &num";

run;

%end;

%else

%do; 

%put Id Number not found. And supplied value was: &num;

run;

%end;

%mend ides;
```

Comment: Homework questions are allowed but please follow the guidelines here on how to structure your question [ask]

Comment: hi Reeza,could you please guide me in constructing the question

Comment: Please just show what you tried.  If it did not run show the lines from the SAS log that state the error in context.  If it ran but did not produce what you wanted explain how the result is wrong.

Comment: %macro ides(num);
%let id=%num;


%if  &num le 9 %then %do;

proc print data=maps.algeria label noobs;

var x y ;

where id=&num;

title "Projected Longitude and Latitudes for Id &num";

run;

%end;

%else

%do; 

%put Id Number not found. And supplied value was: &num;

run;

%end;

%mend ides;

Comment: Did you mix your text and code like that? Edit your question with the code please, do not post it in comments?

Comment: hi tom ,i have tried above syntax ,if &num le 9,it is working fine but if i give 1 ge &num le 9,not working,how can i give the condition

Comment: Hi Reeza,i have edited the code with the syntax which i tried,,thanks for guiding

Comment: Ran it, seems fine to me, so what's your issue? You have extra code in there that's not needed (comment your code!)

Comment: I guess you're not checking it's greater than 1 but I think you can figure out how to add that to your %IF statement.

Comment: yes that is my issue greater than 1 is not working,how to resolve that

Comment: You didn't add a condition for it, so where are you expecting it to work?

Comment: i added its not taking thats why i removed

Comment: Then we can't see what's wrong.

Comment: %if  1 ge &num le 9 %then %do;

Comment: This is what I did

Comment: You've asked the number to be less than or equal to 1, that doesn't seem right...

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty good.  A couple of things.

First thing is you have defined the macro as being named IDES.  So use that name in your tests.  To test it you need to call it multiple times to see if it works as expected for different types of inputs. Something like:

```
%ides(1)
%ides(9)
%ides(8)
%ides(123)
%ides(0)
```

Your posted code has some issues.

First you do not need the first line of the macro.

```
%let id=%num;
```

There is no need to create another macro variable with the same value that NUM has.  Plus that is not how you reference the macro variable NUM.  You use `&` to trigger the macro processor to look for a macro variable.  The `%` is used to look for a macro instead of a macro variable. So that code is trying to execute a macro named NUM instead of return the value of macro variable named NUM.  You have not defined any macro with that name.

You have missed part of the requirements by not testing the lower bound of the range of valid values of ID.  You should see this when you try calling the macro with NUM set to 0 or a negative number.

```
 %if &num ge 1 and &num le 9 %then %do;
```

And a more subtle issues will be detected if you try passing in a non-integer value for NUM.  Or a string that cannot be interpreted as a number at all.

```
 %ides(4.5)
 %ides(fred)
```

If the values of ID can be non-integers then your test of values in the macro %IF statement will need to call the %SYSEVALF() function.  Wihtout that SAS will just use the %EVAL() function to evaluate the condition of the %IF and %EVAL() can only do integer arithmetic, not floating point arithmetic.

```
 %if %sysevalf(&num ge 1 and &num le 9) %then %do;
```

Comment: It worked thanks for helping me Tom